# Using CanCanCan, how do I authorize either/or in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I've got a page for administrating multiple objects (like users and groups), and I want to ensure that only users who have access to create at least one of those types of objects can view the page.

Basically, I want to be able to write something like

```
(authorize! :create, User) || (authorize! :create, Group)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Let me see If I understand, you want that conditional in your view or in your cancan model

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by mixing

```
load_and_authorize_resource :user
load_and_authorize_resource :through => :user
```

this is a convenience helper for calling authorize on all resources in a controller that does something like this:

```
class GroupsController < ActionController::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource
  load_and_authorize_resource :through => :user

  def create
    # Automatically does the following:
    # @group = Group.find(group_params[:id])
    # authorize! :create, @group

    # @user= User.find(group_params[:user_id])
    # authorize! :create, @user
  end

end
```

so where in your controller you load the Group and User objects it will auto authorize them against your rules/Abilities like

```
can [:create], [User, Group]
```

Of course you will need your Groups to be a nested resource:

```
resources :users do
  resources :groups
end
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is to use multiple `can?` statements and raise `AccessDenied` on failure. You also should avoid authorization checks against a model class, and instead authorize against a model instance. See [CanCanCan - Common Mistakes](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/8f93d8164234ee2b7b6e943144804f60fbfe8e9a/docs/check_abilities_mistakes.md#check-abilities---avoid-common-mistakes).

```rb
user = User.new(...)
group = Group.new(...)
raise CanCan::AccessDenied.new(nil, :create, [user, group]) \
  unless can?(:create, user) || can?(:create, group)
```

AccessDenied.new(nil, ..) -> `nil` for the first argument result in the default error message.
See [cancan/exceptions](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/3e7bc1a7baccb199eabc5e6a8b38ce33344525d6/lib/cancan/exceptions.rb#L59).

I'd probably move this into a helper to a method named `def authorize create_group_or_user!`

That said, maybe you are doing too much in this controller? Alternatively, you could make this controller redirect *without authorization* to the appropriate `GroupController` or `UserController`, and perform the appropriate authorization checks in those locations.

Alternate Option 2: Maybe use an `accessible_by` restriction on the content, and don't call `authorize!` at all.